# What is regex for website domain to use in tokenizing while keeping punctuation apart from words?

Tags: python, regex, nltk, tokenize

This is normal output: 
[image]

What I want is to keep domain names as single tokens. For ex: "https://www.twitter.com" should remain as a single token.

My code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize.regexp import RegexpTokenizer

line="My website: http://www.cartoon.com is not accessible."
pattern = r'^(((([A-Za-z0-9]+){1,63}\.)|(([A-Za-z0-9]+(\-)+[A-Za-z0-9]+){1,63}\.))+){1,255}$'
tokeniser=RegexpTokenizer(pattern)

print (tokeniser.tokenize(line))
```

Output:

```
[]
```

What am I doing wrong? Any better regex for domain names?

Edit: The special character must remain as a separate token, like from above example, tokenization must separate ('website' , ':').

Comment: I somewhat understand it, been trying to use it on [this](https://regex101.com/), but I'm not sure how it works!

Comment: Maybe `tokeniser=RegexpTokenizer(r'\S+')` to only grab non-whitespace chunks is enough for you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, That's a nice one! but I still need to separate special characters as tokens. For example: ('accessible' , '.')

Comment: Please add these details to the question then.

Comment: Try [`r'\b(?:http|ftp)s?://\S*\w|\w+|[^\w\s]+'`](https://regex101.com/r/HazY6N/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, updated the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125620/discussion-between-jasmin-shah-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
tokeniser=RegexpTokenizer(r'\b(?:http|ftp)s?://\S*\w|\w+|[^\w\s]+')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HazY6N/1)

**Details**:

- `\b` - leading word boundary (there must be a non-word char before...)
- `(?:http|ftp)s?://` - a protocol, `http`/`https`, `ftp`/`ftps`
- `\S*` - 0+ non-whitespace symbols
- `\w` - a word char (=letter/digit/`_`)
- `|` - or
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `|` - or
- `[^\w\s]+` - 1 or more non-word chars excluding whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 'standard' domain regex

```
import re
line="My website: http://www.cartoon.com is not accessible."
print(re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', line))
```

Returns: ['http://www.cartoon.com']

Also works for like 99% of domain names

Comment: What's that hexadecimal piece at the end for?